# How can get image of items in checkout cart

Tags: product, image

I  need to get all data in checkout cart and with below code I can get all data instead of image, I want to get image of items in checkout like in checkout cart that when click on image go to page of product. How can I do it?

```
<?php 
    $items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();  
    foreach($items as $item) {                                   
            echo 'Product Name: '.$item->getName().'<br>';  
            echo 'Product Image: '.$item->getImageUrl().'<br>';                                 
            if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()):  
            $_incl = $this->helper('checkout')->getPriceInclTax($item);  
            echo 'Product Price: '. $this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_incl- $item->getWeeeTaxDisposition());  
            else:  
                echo 'Product Price: '. $magento_style_price = Mage::helper('core')->currency($item->getPrice());  
            endif;  
                echo "<br>";  
                 }  
                // Total items added in cart  
                $totalItems = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount();  
                // Total Quantity added in cart  
                        $totalQuantity = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsQty();  
                // Sub Total for item added in cart  
                        $subTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();  
                //grand total for for item added in cart  
                $grandTotal = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You `can not get image url` by using  `$item->getImageUrl()`

Need use use Magento catalog image helper:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'thumbnail');
```

Also need to use `getAllVisibleItems()` instead of `getAllItems()`.

Comment: This give me the url of image but I need image of item that user can click on it and go to the product page. now, what should be change?

Answer (score 1):

On cart page, this will work to get item image URL

```
    $item->getProduct()->getImageUrl()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($item->getProduct(), 'small_image')->resize(50,50); 
?>
```